# I am getting an error in Swift 4 as follows :

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, prime-factoring

Execution was interrupted, reason:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use `thread return -x` to return to the state before expression evaluation

```
import UIKit

func numberWhosePrimeFactorIsNeeded(_ number : Int) {
    var a = 1

    for primefactor in 2...600851475143 where number % primefactor == 0 {
        let c = a * primefactor

        if c == 600851475143 {
            print(primefactor)
        } else {
            a = c
        }
    }
}
numberWhosePrimeFactorIsNeeded(600851475143)
```

The error comes only when I put `var a >=1; if a = 0` it doesn't showup. Even though the error exists the code runs till the end.

Answer (score 2):

You're overflowing Int. Here's the path that `(a, primefactor)` takes:

```
1 71
71 839
59569 1471
87625999 6857
6857  // <-- a prime factor gets printed, then it continues....
87625999 59569
5219793134431 104441
545160414753108071 486847
```

`545160414753108071 * 486847` is too big to fit in an Int.

Comment: So what is the solution. The same error occurs when I tried using Int64 too. Please help

Comment: I also put an if else statement so that it doesn't run after i get 6857

Comment: @DrexFranco You can't do math this large in an `Int64` (`Int` is the same size as `Int64` on 64-bit platforms). You would need a BigInt type; Swift doesn't have that in stdlib. You could look at projects like osxgmp (https://github.com/githotto/osxgmp) or BigInteger (https://github.com/kirsteins/BigInteger). There may be others.